# When calling the activity in the external sdk , the Action Bar is not Hiding

Tags: android

I have an external SDK that is imported to my Project. SDK Contains certain activities and corresponding xmls. When i tried to call the activity in that SDK the action bar is not hidden. I tried all the possible solutions. So please help me to find out the problem.

Comment: the SDK that you are using has applied a theme to its activities which has actionbar enabled. Have you applied style in your application tag or to separate activities in your Menifest file?

Comment: @UsmanRana My Application tag -    <application
        android:name=".EnableMultiDex"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/FirstAppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:name,android:theme">

Comment: And style -  <style name="FirstAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="N_MR1">@color/primary_dark</item>
    </style>

Comment: do you have source code of that SDK , if yes then you can change theme in that for those activities as per your will.

Comment: I can't edit that SDK. it is protected. But when i integrated that SDK to sample project (Dummy Project), the action bar is hidden.

Comment: and the style of dummy project and your app is same?

Comment: ya its same.....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this theme

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

When i removed this theme , its work fine.!